# Site setting page not showing any Option with edit permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, sharepoint-permissions, site-settings, settings

Site setting page not showing any option with edit permissions.

[image]

Please find attached screenshot.

Comment: Is it a team site or communication site? Do you have Full Control access on the site?

Comment: It is team site with edit permission on the site

Comment: What option/setting page you want to open exactly? Try using Full Control permissions user account once to check if it shows the options.

Comment: with full control permission user able to all option on setting page

Comment: Then I think it is a correct behavior. Edit permission users have less access on site settings (Contribute permissions, plus:
Manage Lists). Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels

Comment: If you want to manage all site settings, you will have to grant full control permissions to user account.

Comment: No these change showing within 2 days before that all option show in setting page in edit permission.